# saving the form in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I want to save a simple form in Django2

But when I send the form data it gave me an error:

```
 __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

this is my form

```
class Message(forms.Form):
name = forms.CharField(max_length=20,
                       widget=forms.TextInput(
                           attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                  'placeholder': 'Your Name'
                                  }))
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-control',
           'placeholder': 'Your Email'
           }))
messages = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
    attrs={'rows': '5',
           'class': 'form-control',
           'placeholder': 'Write your message...'
           }))
```

this is my view

```
 def index(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Message(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_messages = Message(name=request.POST['name'], email=request.POST['email'],
                               messages=request.POST['messages'])
        new_messages.save()
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = Message()
```

and this is my model

```
class Message(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
email = models.EmailField()
messages = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

I try to change the name to anything you think but it did not work.

how can I fix this?

Comment: You've got two things called Message, the model and the form. Rename the form.

Comment: @DanielRoseman
I changed it but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model and Form have the same name!!!!!

try this code:

```
class MessageForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=20,
                       widget=forms.TextInput(
                           attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                  'placeholder': 'Your Name'
                                  }))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control',
           'placeholder': 'Your Email'
           }))
    messages = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={'rows': '5',
           'class': 'form-control',
           'placeholder': 'Write your message...'
           }))

def index(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Message.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            form = MessageForm()
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to to do like this

```
data=form.cleaned_data
```

And use this dictionary in message model , make sure you have name field in your message model

Comment: Firstly, I edited the question and added my model. 
Secondly, where should I add this !?